# Rank teams in different divisions when there is little inter-division play?

Tags: statistics

How would one rank teams in different divisions when there is little inter-division play?

Basic ELO wouldn't work because if the lowest team in the top division beats the highest team in the lowest division there will be a huge delta for the top division team, even though they might not be that good.  Also, the top teams in each division could have similar ELO ratings even though they are vastly different levels.

Also of note is that sometimes teams move up or down divisions through the season, so a team is not fixed to a division necessarily.

How would I accomplish this ranking?

Comment: If there is little inter-division play, then why are they ranked against each other at all? What information could you possibly have about the relative strength of one division compared to another? You must have inter-division play ...

Comment: Your question reminds me of the matchmaking rating in MOBAs like [LoL or DotA](https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Matchmaking_Rating)

Comment: Example: [lichess](https://lichess.org/) uses [Glicko-2 ratings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glicko_rating_system)

Comment: I said there is some inter-division play.  I need to rank them so I can figure out which division they are to be in next season.

Comment: Do any of those deal with semi-isolated groups?

Comment: what exactly is the problem with glicko-2 or elo? it works fine for LoL, in which groups are "semi-isolated" (in the main ranked queue, there are divisions silver / gold / platinum / diamond, so that most of the time, a silver player will play with other silver players, gold players will play with other gold players, etc. ... if you consistently win in your division you will start to play games with the worst players from the next division up)

Comment: The problem is that in those scenarios the players are placed in the division because of their Elo. All players in a higher group will have higher Elo. But to get to this point they all started in the same group and were promoted later once their Elo improved.  This is not the case in my scenario.

Comment: What exactly is the game you are making this rating system for? It would help a lot to know the motivation